# get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given when trying to override save method in django

Tags: python, django-models

how to fix this?

```
from django.db import models
import pycountry
# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, editable=False)

    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        country_list = []
        for country in pycountry.countries:
            country_list.append(country.name)
        if (self.country_name in country_list):
            self.code = pycountry.countries.get(self.country_name).alpha_3
            super(Country, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I peeked at the `pycountry` API.  The `get` method signature on the `countries` object ultimately looks like this:

```
def get(self, **kw):
    ...
```

In Python speak that means it only accepts "named" arguments. In your code, you're giving the `country_name` as a positional argument.

I couldn't infer from my quick glance at the code what they're expecting you to pass, but from context I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
self.code = pycountry.countries.get(name=self.country_name).alpha_3
```

Notice the slight difference where your argument is explicitly named, not just passed positionally.

This error itself is always a tad confusing because of `self`. Python instance methods always have `self` as an implicit positional argument. It's telling you that `self` is the only valid positional argument (1), but you are passing both `self` and `country_name` positionally (2).